# How to call a datable in the parent form from the child form using C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to create an instance using ParentForm class or Parent class but unable to get the data table already created in the parent form. Please find the below sample of code in the parent form which I'm trying to get from my child form.

```
    private void ParentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BLGridsToControls objBL = new BLGridsToControls();
            dgMainGrid.DataSource = objBL.GetCity();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Note : objBL.GetCity returns a data table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the dataTable to the child form by creating a constructor that accepts a DataTable as a parameter, and then calling that constructor.
E.g.

```
var childForm = new ChildForm(dgMainGrid.DataSource);
childForm.ShowDialog();
```

and in ChildForm:

```
DataTable myDataSource { get; set; }

ChildForm(DataTable myDataTable)
{
     // do something with myDataTable, such as put it into a property for later use, 
     myDataSource = myDataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to pass a reference to the parent form into the child form via the Show() command itself.  The reference can be accessed in the child form via the .Owner property; just cast it back to the parent form type.

So in the Parent form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // in the parent form, pass a reference to the Show() command:
    SomeChildForm scf = new SomeChildForm();
    scf.Show(this); // <-- pass in the parent (this) via Show()
}
```

Over in the Child form:

```
private void Foo()
{
    // in the child form, cast the .Owner property to the parent form type:
    BLGridsToControls objBL = (BLGridsToControls)this.Owner;
    dgMainGrid.DataSource = objBL.GetCity();
}
```

Comment: Thank you  for your valuable time in providing the solution.